# Train a SVM (Support Vector Machine) classifier with Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I want to train different *classifier* with using `Scikit-learn` with following code for **Multi-label classification** problem:

```
names = [
    "Nearest Neighbors",
    "Linear SVM", "RBF SVM", "Gaussian Process",
    "Decision Tree", "Random Forest", "Neural Net", "AdaBoost",
    "Naive Bayes", "QDA"]

classifiers = [
    KNeighborsClassifier(3),
    SVC(C=0.025),
    SVC(gamma=2, C=1),
    GaussianProcessClassifier(1.0 * RBF(1.0)),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5),
    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5),
    MLPClassifier(alpha=0.5),
    AdaBoostClassifier(),
    GaussianNB(),
    QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()]

for name, clf in izip(names, classifiers):
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    score = clf.score(X_train, Y_test)
    print name, score
```

`KNeighbors` classifier works properly but when I reach to the SVM classifier it throws following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/GraphLstm/classifier.py", line 87, in <module>
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 151, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 526, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 562, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (9280, 39)
```

What's the reason and How can I fix that?

**Edit:**  As commented by @Vivek following classifier only allowed for **Multi-label classification**:

```
sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier
sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier
sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifierCV
```

Comment: Only 1-d values are permitted as `y` for SVC. Is this a multi-label classification problem?

Comment: @VivekKumar yes, exactly. It's multi-label classification

Comment: Then you need to change the list of classifiers. Not all classifiers present here are able to do multilabel classification. Please [look here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) to find out more.

Comment: Maybe you have seen it, but you can use [OneVsRestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#one-vs-the-rest) with base estimators SVM or any other which dont inherently support multilabel to support multilabel classifications from them.

Comment: @Vivek thanks, please post your answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a multi-label classification problem, not all estimators in scikit will be able to handle them inherently. The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) provides a list of estimators which support multi-label out of the box like various tree based estimators or others :

```
sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier
sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier
sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier
...
...
```

However there are strategies like **one-vs-all** which can be employed to train the required estimator (which doesn't support multilabel directly). Sklearn estimator [OneVsRestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier) is made for this.

See the [documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#one-vs-the-rest) for more details about it.

Answer (score 3):

The fit function of the [knn classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.fit) allows a matrix as y-value. For the [svm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit) this is not allowed. The error message tries to hint you on a disallowed y-shape

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I fix that? I'm really new to Python things. I took the example from scikit-learn documentations:(

Comment: This depends on the task an of course on the data. Which data set do you use. Which shape does y have?